# Получение изображения курсора над Flash

Tags: delphi, flash

Веб-приложение на делфи, в качестве браузера использую компонент Tchromium. В него загружаю сайт, в котором имеется игра на flash, с помощью кода:

```
var
CI: TCursorInfo;
begin
CI.cbSize := SizeOf(CI);
GetCursorInfo(CI);
Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := CI.hCursor;
```

В image1 получаю изображения курсора. Но если курсор над Flash, и он там заменяется своим курсором, то в image1 ничего не отображается. CI.hCursor равен 351474505, и этому значению равен любой нарисованный курсор из flash.

Как можно получить точное изображение текущего курсора над flash или вообще отследить это изменение?

Comment: Исчерпывающего ответа на мой вопрос я так и не увидел, или это все таки невозможно в данном случае, могу отметить только лучший ответ, для обхода проблемы другим путем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос в следующем - так ли необходимо писать собственную реализацию или можно использовать SCAR Divi? Он как раз позволяет написать свой скрипт. Хукает элементы интерфейса, флэш тоже (например, на нем пишут автокликеры для игр и прочее).

**Обновление**

[[[[@Sergei123](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123)
http://www.scar-divi.com/ - лично мне данное творение очень понравилось. Автор с пониманием дела относится к данному проекту.

[[[[@Sergei123](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123) порадовало, что есть возможность отслеживать появление в flash-игре какой-нибудь картинки и в соответствии с этим предпринимать какие-либо действия (произвести клик по координатам места появления картинки в отслеживаемой области).

И еще. Скрипт - это я погорячился. Программа позволяет создать свое приложение с графическим интерфейсом (я же просто отслеживал все происходящее в бесконечном цикле и производил действия по условию).

Comment: Спасибо, первый раз об этой программе слышу, надо будет изучить.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Интересно конечно, просто непонятно, почему среда разработки scar divi паскалевская может это делать, а delphi нет? Думаю, вполне возможно такой же модуль с функциями запилить и для делфи, которые используются в scar divi. А то свое приложение с нуля переписывать на scar divi не вариант, один компонент Tchromium многого стоит.

Comment: @Sergei123 я так понимаю, используется WinAPI. 

И я не думаю, что стоит смешивать, может быть, вам подойдет вариант стороннего приложения на SCAR Divi и своего. Отдельно-то есть. Вы бы описали суть вашего приложения и что там к чему.

Answer (score 2):

[[@vas](/users/22287/vas)](/users/22287/vas), на счёт "Наверное, никак." очень сомнительный аргумент. )

Ибо всё, что мы видим на своём экране, уже в нашем компьютере, и всё можно вытащить, было бы желание.

Но скорее всего в каждом случае подход будет свой, универсальный вы вряд ли найдёте.

[[@Sergei123](/users/24627/sergei123)](/users/24627/sergei123), это не предусмотрено стандартными API, потому hook мыши вряд ли поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, никак.

flash plugin это по своей сути, hfepth? живущий по своим законам. Его код закрытый, и Вы влезть в него не сможете. Единственное, если игра Ваша, то можно из флеша отдать рисунок курсора через мост js наружу. Но у хрома свой plugin пеппер, посмотрите, может, у него открытые api есть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не моя, в том то и проблема, влезать в нее не хочу, просто поверхностно отследить хотя б событие изменения курсора над ним. У меня получается отследить, только получив значение CI.hCursor, равному 351474505. Но это значение получается над любым объектом с нестандартным курсором, что не получится выполнить нужную логику функции, сейчас вникаю в hook-и на события мыши, не знаю, решит ли оно мою проблему.